# What's a singular differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm reading something on Bessel functions of first-second kind as the solutions to the Bessel diff. equation, and the difference, according to the text, is whether the function is singular or not at the origin. What does that exactly mean for a diff. equation of the form:

$$x^2y_{xx}+xy_x+(x^2-n^2)y=0$$

to be singular?

Specifically, I want to write the solution of a cylindrical symmetrical wave as bessel functions.

Comment: The coefficient of $y_{xx}$ is the culprit. It becomes zero when $x=0$. This is not nice, to suddenly lose the highest derivative in the equation.

Comment: @5pm Then if the term of the second derivative is $x^2y_{xx}$, is it always singular? For example here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html the first term is like that and they say: "which are non-singular at the origin".

Comment: Read carefully: "**solutions** to the Bessel differential equation ... which are nonsingular at the origin." Bessel functions are defined as solutions that do **not** blow up at $x=0$. This is actually related to the singularity of the equation: most solutions of the equation blow up when reaching $x=0$. Bessel functions are special solutions which do not do this.

Comment: @5pm So I have to know the solution, or at least if it diverges in the origin (or is singular), before being able solve it?

Comment: Depends on what you want. If you want a cylindrical symmetric wave, then the solution should not blow up at zero.

Comment: @5pm Really? Approximations for large distances give you amplitudes of the form $1/\sqrt(r)$, which diverges at $0$. Should I not assume similar behaviour for the bessel function?

Comment: Frankly, I don't know what problem about the wave equation we are talking about here. Your question was about an ODE. I'll give an answer to that.

Comment: @5pm I think I confused to different related questions I made. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A linear ODE has a singular point when the coefficient of its highest derivative turns to $0$. Such points are further classified as *regular* and *irregular*. References:

1. [Regular singular point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_singular_point)
2. [Frobenius method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.